# Why can't I appendString in a for Loop?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsstring, nsmutablestring, nsentitydescription

I have the following code that I'm attempting to simply loop through an entity and for each NSPropertyDescription name, append it to a Mutable string that I'll be building a further string out of.

```
   - (void) createCSV {
    NSEntityDescription *anEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Missions" inManagedObjectContext:self.missionDatabase.managedObjectContext];

    NSMutableString *csvString = [NSString string];

    for (NSPropertyDescription *property in anEntity) {
        [csvString appendString:property.name];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",csvString);
}
```

The problem when running the following code is I get a

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Can I not append an NSString to an NSMutableString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again. `csvString` isn't mutable. You're creating an `NSString`. Creating an `NSMutableString` looks like this:

```
 NSMutableString *csvString = [NSMutableString string];
```

Comment: And that is the beauty of a fresh set of eyeballs.  I appreciate the help and feel stupid for not seeing that now.